# nodemon is running but not giving output?

Tags: mongodb, npm, mongoose, nodemon

[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`

[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*

[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json

[nodemon] starting `node .\index.js`

[nodemon] restarting due to changes...

[nodemon] restarting due to changes...

[nodemon] starting `node .\index.js`

[nodemon] restarting due to changes...

[nodemon] restarting due to changes...

[nodemon] starting `node .\index.js`

[nodemon] restarting due to changes...

[nodemon] starting `node .\index.js`

instant of node .\index.js give output

connected to mongoose succesfully

I instal nodemon by command
npm i -D nodemon

Comment: I think npm i -g nodemon solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTANT If nodemon is not working, follow this simple step:

1.Install with:

'npm i -D nodemon'

2.In pakage.json add:

"scripts": { "nodemon": "nodemon index.js" }

3.In Terminal run:

npm run nodemon

4.If this does not work, run this command on your node:

npm i -g nodemon

** 'i' is a shortcut of install.

},

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.